# Flutter Gradle build with error exception

Tags: flutter

i just setup my android studio and vs code and flutter SDK installed but any time i try running the project i get this Gradle error, i cant figure out what the problem is please help me out.
[image]

After running the flutter doctor everything seems to be okay.

[image]

Comment: run ```flutter doctor``` and add your output to the post so I can help where needed.

Comment: please add flutter doctor output

Comment: the flutter doctor came out Ok with no error

Comment: are you able to access http://download.flutter.io/ in your browser ?

Comment: yes in am able to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem might be caused by many factors so lets try some solutions 
after each one rebuild your app if the error message changed or the problem solved please keep us informed

1. run these commands one by one

   flutter channel stable

   flutter upgrade --force

   flutter pub cache repair

   cd your app folder

   flutter clean
2. edit app/build.gradle in your host app such as it includes the local repo
   like in [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup)

   repositories {
     maven {
       url 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io'
     }
   }
3. use VPN and rebuild your app

Comment: Thanks @RYOK SECURITY, I was able to resolve the issue using No-1 of the solutions you listed, it worked perfectly. thank you so much for putting me through.